# css animation iteration on desktop safari

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

I am creating a css animation of a box with an infinite loop that stops when another element has finished its css transition.

using javascript, i am detecting the finished event of the css transition using webkitTransitionEnd, then using jQuery I delete the css animating the box and replacing it with a new class with an iteration count of two. this part works as expected.

what is unexpected is that in desktop safari and mobile browsers, the box still keeps on spinning as it were still on an infinite loops. whereas on desktop chrome and firefox works as expected.

this the css i'm using

```
@keyframes logo {
0% {
transform: rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0);
-moz-transform: rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0);
-ms-transform: rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0);
-webkit-transform: rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0);
}
99% {
transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateY(360deg) rotateZ(360deg);
-moz-transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateY(360deg) rotateZ(360deg);
-ms-transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateY(360deg) rotateZ(360deg);
-webkit-transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateY(360deg) rotateZ(360deg);
}
}

#circle {
background-color: red;
width: 10px;
height: 10px;
position: absolute;
left: 50px;
top: 50px;
border-radius: 50%;
transition-property: all;
transition-duration: 1s }


#box {
background-color: red;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
position: absolute;
left: 100px;
top: 100px;
perspective-origin: 32px 32px; }

.spin {
animation-name: logo;
animation-duration: 1s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-direction: initial;
-moz-animation-name: logo;
-moz-animation-duration: 1s;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-moz-animation-direction: initial;
-webkit-animation-name: logo;
-webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-direction: initial; }

.spin-finish {
animation-name: logo;
animation-duration: 1s;
animation-iteration-count: 2;
animation-direction: initial;
-moz-animation-name: logo;
-moz-animation-duration: 1s;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: 2;
-moz-animation-direction: initial;
-webkit-animation-name: logo;
-webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 2;
-webkit-animation-direction: initial; }

.move { transform: translateX(100px); }
```

here is the jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/65gbbovy/1/

how can i make it work on desktop safari as well?

thanks

Comment: use "-webkit-transition"

Comment: try creating a second keyframes, logo2, and changing animation-name in spin-finish